# OpenLayers 3 How to register Feature Modified event as "featuremodified" in OpenLayer 2

Tags: events, observable, interaction, undo-redo, openlayers-3

I need to implement **Undo / Redo** functionality using **OpenLayers 3** vector editing (just like demonstrated in http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/modify-feature.html for OpenLayers 2).

To keep track of *geometry* changes of *features*, I have to manage a memory stack that will hold changed geometric definitions of features upon user interactions. I know OpenLayers 3 provides observable objects. So `ol.Feature` or `ol.Feature.getGeometry()` can be observed for changes, but I am looking for explicit events emitted by `ol.interaction.Modify`, that should notify me when the *interaction* starts or ends the vector editing operation (just like `"beforefeaturemodified"` and `"featuremodified"` events in OpenLayers 2).

A handler listening for observed *geometry* or *feature* changes can be used for the purpose but it is too expensive because *geometry* of the feature under modification is changed with every pixel move.

I have gone through the official [documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc) of OpenLayers 3 but couldn't find various events that are provided by OpenLayers 2. In most cases the documentation mentions *change* event only. I wonder if such events are not a consideration for Openlayer 3's architecture. If it is so, any suggestions how can I extend the existing `ol.interaction.Modify` to incorporate custom events? thanks.

Comment: There are no such events currently. So I'd just recommend to create issues in ol3 GitHub for that.

Comment: Both OL2 and OL3 are open source. Have you looked at the source code? I have found solutions to specific problems in OL3 by copying functions and modifying them to my purposes.

Comment: Thanks @erilem and @anders-finn. I've created the issue on [github](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2946) and also I have successfully inherited the `ol.interaction.Modify` to incorporate necessary event using `goog.EventTarget` etc. Our company is looking for two answers to decide whether to use openlayers-3 or not in an upcoming project. 1- Is it safe to achieve custom behavior by extending `ol` classes using `goog.base` and `goog.inherits` in terms of future updates of OL3? 2- Will there be any licensing conflicts if these extensions are shipped with commercial products? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting at OpenLayers 3.7.0, *ol.interaction.Modify* emits `modifystart`and `modifyend`. Documentation: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/apidoc/ol.ModifyEvent.html

Example that randomly decides after each modification if it should be kept or reversed (http://jsfiddle.net/rbha7f83/1/):

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    style: overlayStyle
});

// The modify interaction does not listen to geometry change events.
// Changing the feature coordinates will make the modify interaction
// unaware of the actual feature coordinates.
// A possible fix: Maintain a collection used by Modify, so we can reload
// the features manually. This collection will always contain the same
// features as the select interaction.
var selectSource = new ol.Collection();
select.on('select', function (evt) {
    evt.selected.forEach(function (feature) {
        selectSource.push(feature);
    });
    evt.deselected.forEach(function (feature) {
        selectSource.remove(feature);
    });
});

var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: selectSource, // use our custom collection
    style: overlayStyle
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([select, modify]),
    layers: [layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [0, 1000000],
        zoom: 2
    })
});

var originalCoordinates = {};
modify.on('modifystart', function (evt) {
    evt.features.forEach(function (feature) {
        originalCoordinates[feature] = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    });
});
modify.on('modifyend', function (evt) {
    evt.features.forEach(function (feature) {
        if (feature in originalCoordinates && Math.random() > 0.5) {
            feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(
                originalCoordinates[feature]
            );
            delete originalCoordinates[feature];

            // remove and re-add the feature to make Modify reload it's geometry
            selectSource.remove(feature);
            selectSource.push(feature);
        }
    });
})
```

Note that the events are emitted before and after each interaction. Dragging a vertex and then clicking a vertex to remove it (both on the same feature) will trigger two `modifystart` and `modifyend` events.

Comment: I am having trouble with making this a certitude, but I think I currently observe that the original coordinates hold references to the... original coordinates, which make them disappear (and the feature subsequently disappear as well) when reaching the `delete originalCoordinates[feature];`. Leaving the deletion out works as expected, but I don't know wether or not that have a very bad effect ™ on memory usage.